# Setting input filter for an edittext in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using an input filter for an edittext in my project.But the conditions is as follows:

1) The first character of the edittext should be only a letter
2)From the second character onwards it can be a letter,a digit,an underscore or a dot

I have tried the following:

```
 filter_username = new InputFilter() { 
         public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                boolean keepOriginal = true;
                 sb = new StringBuilder(end - start);
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {

                    char c = source.charAt(i);

                    if (isCharAllowed2(c)) // put your condition here
                        sb.append(c);
                    else
                        keepOriginal = false;
                }
                if (keepOriginal)
                    return null;
                else {
                    if (source instanceof Spanned) {
                        SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(sb);
                        TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) source, start, sb.length(), null, sp, 0);
                        return sp;
                    } else {
                        return sb;
                    }           
                }
            }

            private boolean isCharAllowed2(char c) {
                if(sb.length()==0)
                      return Character.isLetter(c);
                else
                return (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)||c=='_'||c=='.');

            }

};
```

I set the filter as:
txtusername.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter_username});

The problem is that i am not able to type letters or digits or the required characters from the second character onwards.How do i fix this issue?

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger to step through your code to find out what is wrong.

Comment: http://eazyprogramming.blogspot.gr/2013/03/restrict-edittext-input-content-using.html

Comment: @Pavlos i have tried that method but it doesnt work fine in Kitkat version.That is why i have used the above.The issue is with isCharallowed2 method.